# Характеристика предложения

Tags: синтаксис

**Сложное предложение**: "Овощи, фрукты, деньги - Майкл выложил всё из своих карманов".
Является ли первое простое предложение здесь назывным, полным и осложнённым однородными членами?

Answer (score 1):

Все предложение в целом - простое с однородными дополнениями и обобщающим словом **все**, стоящим после однородных членов. 
Сравни: Майкл выложил все: фрукты, овощи, деньги. 
Теперь об односоставных предложениях, например "Овощи, фрукты, деньги." Это сложное предложение, каждая часть представляет собой односоставное назывное.